# Mean of absolute value of asymetric random walk

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, expected-value, absolute-value, random-walk

Let $(W_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be an *asymmetric random walk*, starting in zero, such that
\begin{align*}
& P ( W_{n+1} = m+1 \mid W_n = m ) + P ( W_{n+1} = m-1 \mid W_n = m )  =1 \\
\text{ and } p = & P ( W_{n+1} = m+1 \mid W_n = m ) < P ( W_{n+1} = m-1 \mid W_n = m ) = q
\end{align*}
I try to compute $E |W_n|$ in the following way. Write $W_n = -n + 2B_n$ where $B_n \sim \text{Bin} (n, p)$. Then use the *law of the unconscious statistician* to get
\begin{align*}
E | W_n | = \sum _{k=0} ^n |-n + 2k |\cdot \binom{n}{k}\cdot p^k \cdot q ^{n-k}.
\end{align*}
Unfortunately, I'm stuck now. I don't know how to get further. Does someone has some good advise or insight? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you have a Markov process, just compute $$E[W_1]= p-q$$, and so $$E[W_n]=nE[W_1] = n(p-q)$$

Comment: I would like to find $E | W_n | = E ( | W_n | ) \neq E ( W_n)$.